# How to add custom handler on close icon in Material UI TextField component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using Material UI in a Reactjs/Typescript project where I render a search input component using TextField.

The "x" icon is built into the component and clears the value on the input. However, I would like to create my own custom handler to make an api call when the search value is deleted.

I looked at the component and component API docs but haven't come across anything useful. There was another answer that used the browser api to grab the x element and add an event listener, but I would like to avoid directly manipulating the DOM if possible.

[image]

```
<TextField
    id="outlined-search"
    label="Search users"
    type="search"
    variant="outlined"
    style={{ width: '40ch' }}
    value={searchValue}
    inputRef={textRef}
    onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => event.target.value !== " " && 
                      setSearchValue(event.target.value)}
    onKeyPress={() => {}}
/>
```

Comment: I referred - https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#customized-inputs, there the `X` icon doesn't come by default. Can you check once if you are having a layer on top of `TextField` or something like that?

Comment: Figured out why the icon is coming - It is because of `type="search"`. I think if you want a handler on `X` icon click, you can have `type="text"` and use `InputAdornment` `prop`, where in you can pass `icon` or character for `X`.
More about it here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/search#differences_between_search_and_text_types

Comment: Yeah, it is because of type="search" prop and I think I want to keep the default look instead of adding an adornment for now.

Comment: I guess, the best you can do is check if the `value` is `empty` in your `handleChange` and accordingly make API calls or whatever extra logic you want to have? Clicking the `X` should also trigger `handleChange` with `""` value I guess.

Comment: @jaybhatt that seems to do the trick, could/should I then call an async function inside of the setSearchValue callback.

Comment: Added an answer, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like below might help. It will call a business logic/API function when input is empty.

```js
const handleChange = async (event) => {
  setSearchValue(event.target.value)
  
  // API calls here
  if(!event.target.value) {
    const response = await api.get();
  }

}


<TextField
  id="outlined-search"
  label="Search users"
  type="search"
  variant="outlined"
  style={{ width: '40ch' }}
  value={searchValue}
  inputRef={textRef}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: I had this but think your answer is better
`
setState((prevState) => {
          if (prevState.length > event.target.value.length) {
            handleClear();
          }
          return event.target.value;
        });
`

Comment: I think in the snippet you put, it might clear everything in case some user multi selects characters and removes them at the same time.